# how to pre-filter data over a live connection in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, olap, microsoft-live-connect

we have a requirement like connect to JIRA database on a live connection and pre-filter the data before loading  to power BI  but with live connection the DAX query option is not enabled.  Can you please help with this

Answer (score 0):

Live connection is as it says - a live connection. It doesn't support pre-filtering.

If you have access to the database, maybe you can create a view that filters out the data you need and use that as the source in your report? Note that this has an negative impact on live connection performance. Also, you need to be sure that you are allowed to add a custom view to Jira database.